# How to set B2CLogin.com as the default Azure B2C SSO URL programmatically?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'd like to use B2Clogin.com rather than login.microsoftonline.com as the default URL when accessing Azure B2C SSO.

I have read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin and it says that we can use b2clogin.com with RunNow. I'd like to know how to set this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

In your application configuration, you should only have to change references from `https://login.microsoftonline.com` to `https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com`.

Comment: I tried it and did not work. Here is the config entry: <add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://MyTenant.b2clogin.com/{0}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={1}" />. Replaced {0} with mytenant.onmicrosoft.com & {1} with policyid

Comment: Can anyone help in resolving this issue? We are working on a project & need to resolve this. I am using the sample from github to make it work. Here is the sample url: git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi.git

Comment: Hi @Kris Are you including "https://" in the **ida:AadInstance** value? The full value should be similar to `https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_mypolicy/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`.

Comment: @ADB2C community & product PMs - Can anyone share a working example?

Comment: My previous comment is a working example. What error or issue are you experiencing or facing?

Comment: I changed the settings as mentioned, but it still shows up login.microsoftonline.com. It is not going to b2clogin.com url. Can you share full sample if you have?

Comment: Product PMs - Can you please confirm if there is a working sample on this? I assume there is not based on the discussions so far. I need to send a final communication to one of the customers if it is possible or not. I wait for your reply till Wednesday (9/12).

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

here is my code and it works with b2clogin.com:

## This is important:

If your TenantName: xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com, the tenant is then xxxxxxxx
(it refers to my variable :)

```
namespace wp_front
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = Configuration["signUpInPolicy"];
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect(Configuration.GetSection("Azure").GetSection("signUpPolicy").Value, GetOpenIdConnectOptions(Configuration.GetSection("Azure").GetSection("signUpPolicy").Value))
                .AddOpenIdConnect(Configuration.GetSection("Azure").GetSection("signInPolicy").Value, GetOpenIdConnectOptions(Configuration.GetSection("Azure").GetSection("signInPolicy").Value))
                .AddOpenIdConnect(Configuration.GetSection("Azure").GetSection("signUpInPolicy").Value, GetOpenIdConnectOptions(Configuration.GetSection("Azure").GetSection("signUpInPolicy").Value))
                .AddOpenIdConnect(Configuration.GetSection("Azure").GetSection("editProfilePolicy").Value, GetOpenIdConnectOptions(Configuration.GetSection("Azure").GetSection("editProfilePolicy").Value))

                .AddCookie();

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }

        private Action<OpenIdConnectOptions> GetOpenIdConnectOptions(string policy)
            => options =>
            {
                options.MetadataAddress =
                    $"https://{Configuration.GetSection("Azure").GetSection("Tenant").Value}.b2clogin.com/{Configuration.GetSection("Azure").GetSection("TenantName").Value}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={policy}";
                options.ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("Azure").GetSection("ClientId").Value;
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin/" + policy;
                options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout/" + policy;
                options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                options.Events.OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ProtocolMessage.Error) &&
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription) &&
                        context.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.StartsWith("AADB2C90091"))
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/");
                        context.HandleResponse();
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                };
            };
    }
}
```